Does an ocean or sea count as Running Water against a vampire?
The vampire stat block states (Monster Manual, p.297):

Vampire Weaknesses.
The vampire has the following flaws:
[...]
Harmed by Running Water. The vampire takes 20 acid damage if it ends its turn in running water.

If I were to run a nautically themed Curse of Strahd campaign, could the players simply knock Strahd into the ocean to make this weakness take effect, or, is the only running water like a river that has an effect on the vampire?
My thought is that a stream or river's water moves continuously in roughly one direction and roughly constant speed (excluding some seasonal outliers), whereas an ocean's movement is subject to tides and waves, so the movement is not consistent in a direction, and may not be considered 'running' because of this movement.
Currents in an ocean do tend to move in one direction, but for something the size of a humanoid the wake of a boat, the wind blowing, and creatures moving below the surface are more likely to affect the water around the creature, thus not putting the creature in 'running' water, just moving water, which seems to not count as 'running'.
If the ocean can be considered running water, would the doldrums be considered standing water?
While the ocean as a whole is moving, this one particular area is stationary, is that enough to remove the 'running' tag to this water?

Heavily related, although I wouldn't consider it a duplicate: What is considered "running water" for the vampire's weakness?

Reminder that answers, partial answers, suggestions on where to find an answer, frame challenges, and general advice to the asker do not belong in comments.

For some reason I am now imagining a vampire engulfed by a water elemental darting around causing the vampire to take 20 acid damage each round

It's ambiguous
Typically, oceans and lakes are not considered running water, which refers specifically to rivers and streams, so you should feel free to make whichever rulings make the most sense for the game you want to run.
But honestly, feel free to bend or replace the Monster Manual write-up to do what you want to do. Real-life vampire lore is broad, varied, and often self-contradictory (because there isn't actually one single body of 'vampire lore', but a large complex of local stories and beliefs that don't take into account what the next county over might think). You have all the justification you need to make up rules about how your vampire captain is going to work. As long as the rules are consistent in your adventure, you should be fine. Any complaints ought to be easily quashed with a simple "These are a different kind of vampire with different weaknesses", if necessary.
Dracula
As an example of a vampire with different weaknesses than D&D uses, a great deal of what people think of today as vampire lore is based on Bram Stoker's Dracula -- which, realistically, was Stoker picking and choosing a handful of elements from different vampire myths and mashing them together into something more-or-less coherent.
In the story, there's no special effect of running water specifically; Dracula is unable to cross bodies of water under his own power. He must be transported across the sea in the hold of the Demeter. He's able to come out of his coffin to murder the crew, so long as he remains on deck, but is apparently unable to cross over the ocean's surface. Once the ship arrives in England, he does not leave the ship until it runs aground, at which point he immediately leaps onto the beach (in wolf-form) and flees the area. It's notable that he didn't simply go into bat-form (which he uses elsewhere in the novel) and fly to the shore as soon as he was within the harbor. Instead, he remained on the ship until it actually made contact with dry land.
You should feel free to use this lore or ignore it to whatever degree you like.

But in the game, Dracula would be fine flying OVER running water, river, ocean, or uncle Charlie's overflowing diapers. The vampire takes 20 acid damage if it ends its turn IN running water.

Arguably, some lakes should count, and others shouldn't. If the lake has both input(s) and output(s), then it's functionally just a wider, possibly slower moving (at any given point) part of a river, but it's still running downhill to the ocean eventually. If it's produced by a spring and is solely the source of a river (no inflow aside from spring(s)), or the terminus of a river with no outlets (like the Dead Sea or the Caspian Sea), it wouldn't be "running", but the in-between is where judgment calls come in (just how slow does the flow have to be before it stops being "running").

I do think you're overstating the tie to Dracula here. Bram Stoker's water-related weakness is separate from a fairly common weakness of supernatural beings in European folklore, the inability to cross running water. The exact rationale isn't clear (maybe associated with Jesus being baptized in a river; maybe a simple association that running water was safer and cleaner to live near than stagnant water, bestowing a holy aura on it; maybe tied, for vampires, to their ties to their home soil, with rivers marking territory boundaries), but it shows up for fairies, vampires, witches, etc.

@MindwinRememberMonica Nobody is arguing anything else. What's your point?

@ShadowRanger I'm not saying there's a link between Drac and D&D; quite the opposite. Dracula is a famous example of a vampire that definitely doesn't follow the D&D rules at all. The point is that we as DMs should not feel constrained by the monster manual writeup. Whether an ocean should 'count' as running water or not is really fairly irrelevant because the real question is what rules will serve the game you're trying to run.

@DarthPseudonym clarification. The stack exchange is a collaborative knowledge-base-building effort. Adding more information is always a good thing. Do not misconstrue such efforts with criticism.

"Typically, oceans and lakes are not considered running water" I disagree, on the premise that running water seems to be used here to refer to a geographical water feature as opposed to merely touching any kind of water (think Wicked Witch, water burns her). Additionally, if you interpret running water to be used as an antonym for stagnant water (in the sense that stagnant water is considered non-potable and easily polluted); the sea and ocean is a moving body of water, enough to not be considered stagnant.

The only other remaining interpretation, which your answer would then be based on when you exclude the two I just listed, would be the kinetic energy imparted to the water. If that were the case, it makes little sense for it to have to be water specifically, just any moving non-gaseous material would impart said kinetic energy.

@Flater I'm not sure what you're arguing here.  Running water, as a historical term predating plumbing, has always referred to features like rivers and streams, but not typically to lakes, nor to the ocean. That's just what the phrase means.

The DM decides.
When we’re talking about definitions of words that aren’t game terms, the DM has to make a ruling. “Running water” is not a game term with a game-specific definition in the rules, so the DM decides.
For your specific game, think about what makes the most sense for your adventure’s main villain. Is he the vampire Lord of the Sea? Then it probably doesn’t bother him that much.

I would add: Also consider the players' likely reactions and use of world knowledge like this, then decide whether any of the decisions need foreshadowing or should be kept as reveals only if players try them. Some players like to find out by doing, but some like to plan and theorycraft, and you don't necessarily want the latter types feeling their plans have been "unfairly" nerfed through rulings in favour of monsters.

"Running water" in this context typically refers to waters with a current.
The more modern version of "running water" that we tend to think of is "running water from the tap," which still makes 'running water' a synonym for 'flowing water'.
Oceans, streams, rivers, tributaries, etc. all have a current and a/multiple direction(s) of flow.
An isolated, man-made lake with no connecting bodies of water, or a still canal, like a filled tub of water, would be an example of water that does not count as running.
Running Water isn't a game term, but with Plain English being the default rule of 5e, this 'reading' removes most dilemmas around the rule, at least until someone throws a vampire in a full bathtub under a running tap, or a horse trough under a water pump.
<I'd probably give the player inspiration for trying a funny and let them know it unfortunately doesn't work in that case.>
So what about an ocean, and in particular a doldrum?
An ocean has currents and water flows into it from multiple sources called estuaries, so for the purposes of this scenario it should count.
Doldrums refer to regions of water near the equator that are windless, where sailing ships get stuck. While this reduces wave chop, that has no impact on the flow of the currents in the water itself.

@enkryptor Yes; it has currents and water flows into it from multiple sources called estuaries.

I'm not 100% sure what the downvote is for to be honest, aside from the odd running tap comparison. This seems like a valid take: flowing water is "running", and therefore ocean currents are running water and inhibit a vampire. Maybe consider removing some of the fluff, and clarify why doldrums are important to the question?

@TheLittlePeace I'm unsure how to pare down the fluff without detracting from the explanation of "flowing." The bit about Doldrums is important to the question because it's specifically asked in the OP, however.
